# jQuery Accordion Collapse with No Items Active

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a jQuery accordion that by default on page load has all items collapsed. It allows a user to click on an item to open for content and click on the same item to collapse it. A user may also click on another item to open that content and close the previous item. The usual.

What I want to be able to do is when I close the open item by clicking on it, make it inactive like when the page loads. When I click on the item, the content closes but the item is still active and the CSS for the open item is visible. How do I make it inactive on close so that it goes to default state?

Comment: You may need to provide some code. Without the code, we have no idea what's going on with your accordion :)

Comment: It's for work so I'm unsure if I am allowed to. Basically the .ascx file registers the accordion widget. In the javascript file is where the functions are stored. In the .ascx file, I set the following properties: 

collapsible: true, 
    autoHeight: false, 
    active: false 

As I click another item, that item becomes active. What I want to do is when the item collapses (without clicking a different item), for it to not be active

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's impossible to help. Post some excerpts at least.What kind of "jquery accordion" are you using?
Most likely the accordion has some css that makes an item **appear** "active"; you could check for clicks on an item (ie it is being closed, but not because some other item opens, but because the items is "minimized") and then revoke the css that makes it appear active.

Comment: I actually no longer work there but  I did find a solution to this problem. Thank you.